# Apple store said my screen is busted and needs external display. Screen randomly turned on before disposal.?

Tags: battery, screen

I have a mid 2014 MBP 13" Retina, bought at an Apple Authorized reseller in 2018 brand new though (it was a custom and special order that's why I got it new in 2018.)

Laptop is fine except the battery is on "service recommended" already (just 3 months ago). 2 days ago the screen is just black but still works with a monitor.

I've been using it with a monitor, but then yesterday suddenly the screen worked! It was like that the until this morning when the display went black again. It's been like that for hours until just 4 minutes ago, when screen suddenly turned on again while I was using it!

What the hell? Just tell me if its busted or not cause I don't want false hope. Im still saving up money to buy a new one.

Do you think this is a battery issue since mine is "service recommended" already?

Comment: Apple doesn't sell custom configuration of a 4 year old device as "new."  Are you sure this wasn't a refurb or "scratch and dent?" Your battery has failed, it needs to be serviced.  The display cable or the video driver chip is giving you issues, you need to take it in for service.  Either way, we can only guess what the issue is.  You need a professional to put hands on and do a fulll diagnosis.

Comment: @Allan Oh it was from an authorized apple reseller since we dont have an actual apple store in my country. It was new and checked the serial too. I did go to the apple store repair and said the screen needs replaced. I dont think they wanna open it

Comment: It's a 5-year-old laptop, so there is no "already", when it comes to the battery.

Comment: @MarcWilson sure but what can i do about this screen issue?

Comment: @user139754 Pay to have the screen repaired.  It won't be cost-effective, but it is what it is.